# QSslError: The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm trying send a rest request to a webservice where the certificate is selfsigned. At the moment I'm creating a request, setting the url and the auth. key as headers. Then I tell the reply to ignore this ssl error:

```
QSslError error(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate);
QList<QSslError> expectedSslErrors;
expectedSslErrors.append(error);

QNetworkReply *reply = _accessManager.put(request, ""); // no requestbody
reply->ignoreSslErrors(expectedSslErrors);
```

When I run it I get the following ssl error:

> 9 - The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted

followed by network error nr 6:

> Request failed with message: SSL handshake failed

At the moment I'm ignoring ALL errors since it seems to be the only thing that works. Feel dirty.

Would be really grateful if anyone know what I'm doing wrong!

EDIT:

Changed to:

```
QList<QSslError> expectedSslErrors;
expectedSslErrors.append(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate);
expectedSslErrors.append(QSslError::CertificateUntrusted);
reply->ignoreSslErrors(expectedSslErrors);
```

But still getting the same error...

Answer (score 6):

> The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted

The problem is the "untrusted" part. 
You have to provide the self signed certificate, as second parameter of `QSslError`.

**Edit:** Based on the source code, the comparison between the actually received SSL errors and the errors passed to `ignoreSslErrors` is done by comparing both the error code, and the certificate. 

So if the error returned by OpenSSL would contain a certificate, like with `QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate`, you must always pass a certificate to `QSslError` constructor, or the comparison would fail.

But you can also ignore the error manually by connecting the signal `sslError()` to a slot where you check that the error list contains only a self signed certificate error, and then call `ignoreSslErrors()` (without any parameter).

Comment: what do you mean by providing the cert? its a base64 encoded string that is part of the auth. header. not to sure how to provide that as a a cert

Comment: @chikuba What you describe looks more like the basic authentication, not a certificate. The doc shows how you can pass the certificate to `QSslError` from a file, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#ignoreSslErrors-2), and to get that file, go with your browser on the server, and when you click on the padlock, you should be able to download/export the certificate.

Comment: there is no certificate, the the padlock is crossed over. the site is not trusted. thought that when you used self-signed you didnt need a cert

Comment: A self-signed site has a certificate, but it's not verified by a known authority (like Verisign), only by the site owner. If you trust the site owner and you got the certificate through a secure way (so, not the method I wrote :) ), it is as safe as a authority signed certificate.

Comment: Even if the padlock is crossed over, you can download the certificate (on chrome with the site from that [example](https://onlinessl.netlock.hu/en/test-center/self-signed-ssl-certificate.html) it works).

Comment: oh i see. the thing that confuses me the most is that i did not have to do this in python, just qt

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, what you need to do is call ignoreSslErrors on a slot that responds to the QNetworkReply::sslErrors signal